# How to add a scrollbar to a Flutter website and optimize animation alignment?

Tags: flutter, responsive-design, scrollbar

I'm building a Flutter website and have two related issues:

**1. Adding a Scrollbar:**

I want to integrate a scrollbar into my website (like the example in the second image). Currently, content may overflow. How can I add a scrollbar that's functional and visually appealing?

**2. Optimizing Animation Alignment:**

My website features a timer animation. While it works, I'm noticing alignment inconsistencies between mobile and desktop views, especially when the timer starts. Here's how I'm currently using Responsive Sizer:

```
Device.screenType == ScreenType.mobile
  ? Scaffold // Mobile layout
  : Scaffold // Desktop layout
```

How can I ensure the animation aligns consistently across different screen sizes and avoid any lag on the website?

**Code:**

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    ThemeData themeData = Theme.of(context);
    return ResponsiveSizer(builder: (context, orientation, screenType) {
      return Device.screenType == ScreenType.mobile
          ? Scaffold(
              backgroundColor:
                  LongBreak ? Color(0xffD94530) : Color(0xff6351c5),
              body: GestureDetector(
                onTap: () {
                  if (controller.isDismissed) {
                    showModalBottomSheet(
                      context: context,
                      builder: (context) => Container(
                        height: 300,
                        child: CupertinoTimerPicker(
                          initialTimerDuration: controller.duration!,
                          onTimerDurationChanged: (time) {
                            setState(() {
                              controller.duration = time;
                            });
                          },
                        ),
                      ),
                    );
                  }
                },
                child: AnimatedBuilder(
                    animation: controller,
                    builder: (context, child) {
                      return Stack(
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Align(
                            alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                            child: Container(
                              color: Color(0xffD94530),
                              height: controller.value *
                                  MediaQuery.of(context).size.height *
                                  0.715,
                            ),
                          ),
                          Padding(
                            padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                            child: Column(
                              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                              children: <Widget>[
                                Expanded(
                                  child: Align(
                                    alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                                    child: Align(
                                      alignment: FractionalOffset.bottomCenter,
                                      child: SingleChildScrollView(
                                        child: Column(
                                          mainAxisAlignment:
                                              MainAxisAlignment.end,
                                          crossAxisAlignment:
                                              CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                                          children: <Widget>[
                                            Text(
                                              countText,
                                              style: TextStyle(
                                                fontSize: 90.0,
                                                color: Color(0xffFAFAFA),
                                              ),
                                            ),
                                          ],
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ),
                                Expanded(
                                  child: Row(
                                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                    crossAxisAlignment:
                                        CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                                    children: [
                                      AnimatedBuilder(
                                          animation: controller,
                                          builder: (context, child) {
                                            return Padding(
                                              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                                  vertical: 2.0,
                                                  horizontal: 15.0),
                                            );
                                          }),
                                      AnimatedBuilder(
                                          animation: controller,
                                          builder: (context, child) {
                                            return Padding(
                                              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                                  vertical: 2.0,
                                                  horizontal: 15.0),
                                              child:
                                                  FloatingActionButton.extended(
                                                      backgroundColor:
                                                          Color(0xffFAFAFA),
                                                      onPressed: () {
                                                        if (controller
                                                            .isAnimating) {
                                                          controller.stop();
                                                          setState(() {
                                                            LongBreak = false;
                                                          });
                                                        } else {
                                                          controller.reverse(
                                                              from: controller
                                                                          .value ==
                                                                      0
                                                                  ? 1.0
                                                                  : controller
                                                                      .value);
                                                          setState(() {
                                                            LongBreak = false;
                                                          });
                                                        }
                                                      },
                                                      icon: Icon(
                                                        controller.isAnimating
                                                            ? Icons.pause
                                                            : Icons.play_arrow,
                                                        color:
                                                            Color(0xff3B3B3B),
                                                      ),
                                                      label: Text(
                                                        controller.isAnimating
                                                            ? "Pause"
                                                            : "Pomoworko",
                                                        style: TextStyle(
                                                            color: Color(
                                                                0xff3B3B3B)),
                                                      )),
                                            );
                                          }),
                                      SizedBox(width: 20, height: 100),
                                    ],
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      );
                    }),
              ),
            )
          : Scaffold(
              backgroundColor:
                  LongBreak ? Color(0xffD94530) : Color(0xff6351c5),
              body: GestureDetector(
                onTap: () {
                  if (controller.isDismissed) {
                    showModalBottomSheet(
                      context: context,
                      builder: (context) => Container(
                        height: 300,
                        child: CupertinoTimerPicker(
                          initialTimerDuration: controller.duration!,
                          onTimerDurationChanged: (time) {
                            setState(() {
                              controller.duration = time;
                            });
                          },
                        ),
                      ),
                    );
                  }
                },
                child: AnimatedBuilder(
                    animation: controller,
                    builder: (context, child) {
                      return Stack(
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Align(
                            alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                            child: Container(
                              color: Color(0xffD94530),
                              height: controller.value *
                                  MediaQuery.of(context).size.height *
                                  0.615,
                            ),
                          ),
                          Padding(
                            padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                            child: Column(
                              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                              children: <Widget>[
                                Expanded(
                                  child: Align(
                                    alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                                    child: Align(
                                      alignment: FractionalOffset.bottomCenter,
                                      child: SingleChildScrollView(
                                        child: Column(
                                          mainAxisAlignment:
                                              MainAxisAlignment.end,
                                          crossAxisAlignment:
                                              CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                                          children: <Widget>[
                                            Text(
                                              countText,
                                              style: TextStyle(
                                                fontSize: 90.0,
                                                color: Color(0xffFAFAFA),
                                              ),
                                            ),
                                          ],
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ),
                                Expanded(
                                  child: Row(
                                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                    crossAxisAlignment:
                                        CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                                    children: [
                                      AnimatedBuilder(
                                          animation: controller,
                                          builder: (context, child) {
                                            return Padding(
                                              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                                  vertical: 2.0,
                                                  horizontal: 15.0),
                                            );
                                          }),
                                      AnimatedBuilder(
                                          animation: controller,
                                          builder: (context, child) {
                                            return Padding(
                                              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                                  vertical: 2.0,
                                                  horizontal: 15.0),
                                              child:
                                                  FloatingActionButton.extended(
                                                      backgroundColor:
                                                          Color(0xffFAFAFA),
                                                      onPressed: () {
                                                        if (controller
                                                            .isAnimating) {
                                                          controller.stop();
                                                          setState(() {
                                                            LongBreak = false;
                                                          });
                                                        } else {
                                                          controller.reverse(
                                                              from: controller
                                                                          .value ==
                                                                      0
                                                                  ? 1.0
                                                                  : controller
                                                                      .value);
                                                          setState(() {
                                                            LongBreak = false;
                                                          });
                                                        }
                                                      },
                                                      icon: Icon(
                                                        controller.isAnimating
                                                            ? Icons.pause
                                                            : Icons.play_arrow,
                                                        color:
                                                            Color(0xff3B3B3B),
                                                      ),
                                                      label: Text(
                                                        controller.isAnimating
                                                            ? "Pause"
                                                            : "Pomoworko",
                                                        style: TextStyle(
                                                            color: Color(
                                                                0xff3B3B3B)),
                                                      )),
                                            );
                                          }),
                                      SizedBox(width: 20, height: 100),
                                    ],
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      );
                    }),
              ),
            );
    });
  }
}
```

**This is my Flutter site:**

[image]

**I want to add a scrollbar on my website like this, for example:**

[image]

**What I've Tried:**

- I've experimented with Responsive Sizer to distinguish mobile and desktop layouts, but I'm still facing alignment challenges.
- I've researched scrollbar implementation in Flutter web but haven't found a solution that fits my use case.

**Additional Notes:**

I'm aiming for a user-friendly and polished appearance for my website.

**Thanks in advance for your expertise!**

Comment: Did you try this package? https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_web_scrollbar

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried the Scrollbar view widget for implementing the Scrollbar?

It goes like this:

```
​import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(const MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  static const String _title = 'Flutter Code Sample';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: _title,
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: const Text(_title)),
        body: const MyStatelessWidget(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyStatelessWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyStatelessWidget({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scrollbar(
      child: GridView.builder(
        itemCount: 120,
        gridDelegate:
            const SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(crossAxisCount: 3),
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
          return Center(
            child: Text('item $index'),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Make sure that you have a fixed height widget in the Scrollbar, or there maybe chances for errors like the pixel overflow

Comment: Hello, how to fix height widget in the Scrollbar?

Answer (score 1):

Wrap the content of the body of scaffold with a scrollbar widget

```dart
Scrollbar(
 thicknesses: 10,
 child: GestureDetector()
)
```